# Get SlugField of User model into the DeleteView of a other model - Django

Tags: django, django-generic-views

I created a DeleteView for a model (Bezoeker) which is related to the User model. Because I am referencing the Bezoeker Model in the DeleteView it cannot find the Slugfield of the user model. I thought specifying it in my get_context_data method would do the job (did this with the rest of my views as well).

The error message I am getting is telling me that the slugfield is found but the pk is empty. When I type in the supposed url in the browser it works and it directs my to the appropriate instance based on the Pk.

*Reverse for 'gast-verwijderen' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '-2', 'pk': ''}' not found.*

**My view:**

```
class GastDeleteView(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Bezoeker
    login_url = 'users:login'
    redirect_field_name = 'register:gastenlijst'
    #success_url = reverse_lazy('register:gastenlijst')
    template_name = 'register/gast-verwijderen.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(
            pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
            bezoeker=get_object_or_404(Bezoeker, pk=self.kwargs['pk']),
            slug=self.kwargs['slug'],
            bedrijf=get_object_or_404(Bedrijf, slug=self.kwargs['slug'])
        )
        return context

    def get_success_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return reverse_lazy('register:gastenlijst', args=[
            {"slug": self.kwargs['slug'],
             "pk": self.kwargs['pk']}
        ])
```

**My url:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug>/dashboard/gastenlijst/verwijderen/<pk>/', GastDeleteView.as_view(), name='gast-verwijderen'),
]
```

**My template:**

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'register:gast-verwijderen' slug=slug pk=pk %}">X</a>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this one was easier then I thought. Just needed to reference the pk=bezoeker.id in the template.

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{% url 'register:gast-verwijderen' slug=slug pk=bezoeker.id %}">X</a>
```

Did the job!